# How to display the environment name on login screen Oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

We have three web-links (URLs) for opening the oracle forms application: `PROD, STG and DEV`.

I want to display the current environment on login screen as per the weblink user is opening. like,

1. If user is opening the Prod weblink, it should display the
   `Production` on login screen.
2. If user is opening Dev weblink, it should display the `Development`.

I am using `oracle forms suit 10g`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do these links have different IPs?

Comment: they have different IPs as i can see the difference in suffix. however, just to be sure using any IP, i can connect to either Prod or non-prod schema.

Answer (score 0):

If your Dev/Production/staging use different IPs then you can use `SYS_CONTEXT` function to return the IP address and then use `set_window_property' on WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE to set the required title

Ex, on WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE trigger

```
DECLARE
   v_ip_address VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
   SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS') 
   INTO v_ip_address 
   from DUAL;

   IF v_ip_address = V_PROD_IP THEN
      SET_WINDOW_PROPERTY('WINDOW_NAME', 'TITLE','Prod');
   ELSIF v_ip_address = V_STAGE_IP THEN
      SET_WINDOW_PROPERTY('WINDOW_NAME', 'TITLE','Staging');
   ELSIF v_ip_address = V_DEV_IP THEN
      SET_WINDOW_PROPERTY('WINDOW_NAME', 'TITLE','Dev');
   END IF;
```

Where

- V_PROD_IP, V_STAGE_IP, V_DEV_IP are IPs corresponding to different environments
- WINDOW_NAME is the name of the root(base) window

Answer (score 0):

They probably connect to a different DB schema. So then you can use the following:

```
DECLARE
   luser VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
   select user
   into   luser
   from   dual;

   IF luser = 'PRODUCTIONSCHEMA' THEN
      SET_WINDOW_PROPERTY('WINDOW_NAME', 'TITLE','Prod');
   ELSIF luser = 'STAGINGSCHEMA' THEN
      SET_WINDOW_PROPERTY('WINDOW_NAME', 'TITLE','Staging');
   ELSIF luser = 'DEVELOPMENTSCHEMA' THEN
      SET_WINDOW_PROPERTY('WINDOW_NAME', 'TITLE','Dev');
   END IF;
END;
```